# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work in running my tests

Tags: hibernate, testing, gradle, version

So this is the error log which I am getting while running tests:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/internal/ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    ... 48 common frames omitted

2016-02-25 20:28:16.792  WARN 3257 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' is defined)
2016-02-25 20:28:16.793 ERROR 3257 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@5f282abb] to prepare test instance [com.opensecret.Service.user.UserServiceImplTest@6f195bc3]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) ~[spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228) ~[spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/internal/ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/internal/ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    ... 48 common frames omitted

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/internal/ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/internal/ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 48 more
```

This is my **build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.1.RELEASE'
        junitVersion = '4.12'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
    }
}

apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 

jar {
    baseName = 'open-secret'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("junit:junit:${junitVersion}")
    testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-core")
    testCompile("org.hsqldb:hsqldb")
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}
```

This is my **application-test.properties** file which is api/src/test/com/myapp/resources:

```
spring.profiles.active: test
spring.jpa.database: HSQL
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:hsqldb:mem:opensecret
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-username=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
spring.datasource.username: root
spring.datasource.password: password
```

And this is my UserServiceImplTest:

```
package com.opensecret.Service.user;

import com.opensecret.OpenSecretApplication;
import com.opensecret.model.Authority;
import com.opensecret.model.UserInfo;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@Rollback(true)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {OpenSecretApplication.class })
public class UserServiceImplTest{

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
        userInfo.setEmail("abc@email.com");
        userInfo.setUsername("james");
        userInfo.setPassword("password");
        userInfo.setAuthority(Authority.USER.toString());
        userInfo.setEnabled(true);
        userInfo.setCreated_at(new Date());
        userInfo.setUpdated_at(new Date());
        userService.createUser(userInfo);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAllUsers() throws Exception {
        Collection<UserInfo> users = userService.getAllUsers();
        assertEquals(users.size(), 1);

        List userList = new ArrayList(users);
        UserInfo user = (UserInfo) userList.get(0);
        assertEquals(user.getEmail(),"abc@email.com");
        assertEquals(user.getUsername(),"james");
        assertEquals(user.getPassword(),"password");
        assertEquals(user.getAuthority(),"USER");
        assertEquals(user.isEnabled(),true);
    }
}
```

I think its related to some version issue but not sure.So I have one more **application.properties** file which is in my **api/src/main/com/myapp/resources** which is this

```
 server.port: 9000
management.port: 9001
management.address: 127.0.0.1

spring.datasource.catalog=opensecret
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${spring.datasource.catalog}
spring.datasource.driver-class-username=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
```

So having two file application.properties, is this causing this error or some other issue? Need help.

Answer (score 0):

Its not because of two "application.properties" file.

You may want to change the dependencies section in the "build.gradle" file like below and it should work

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: springBootVersion
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: springBootVersion
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: springDataJpaVersion
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: springBootVersion
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.30'
```